# Page Speed Insight suggests that I remove unused JavaScript, but those scripts are needed for the pages to work

Tags: seo, javascript, google-pagespeed

I deferred all my scripts in this way

```
<script defer src="https://mywebsite/javascript/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" >
```

but Page Speed Insights wants me to remove them. I cannot remove them. The Report [Link](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedfilm.com%2Fmovies%2Fwatch%2F767%2F&tab=mobile&hl=en)
[image]

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not loading it from a CDN? Are you actually using jQuery? The top culprit is base.js from YouTube, are you using that?

Comment: the jquery file is jquery + jquery ui but I use sitelock CDN in the website. I used YouTube, yes